# How to dynamically check if abstract JSON objects match a specific interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In js/typescript, if I have an interface like this

```
interface B {
   bar:string;
}

interface A {
   foo:string;
   bar:B;
}
```

and then I have a abstract JS object like this

```
const r = await fetch("https://mylink.com");
const d = await r.json();
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
const matches:boolean = Matches(d, A);
```

which then is a boolean telling me if it is an exact match or not?

Thanks

Comment: You should be using a TypeScript-first validation library at this point, like [`zod`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod).

Comment: Is there a way I can convert an existing typescript interface into a zod schema?

Comment: yes https://www.google.com/search?q=interface+to+zod+schema&oq=interface+to+zod+schema&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.4680j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I meant dynamically in the code in runtime.